# I Can not disable button due to error Cannot implicitly convert type string to bool

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to disable search button after some  information is displayed in the grid view.  when i wrote "btnSearch.Enabled="false";" in the grid view button, Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool' message will raise may give me solution please ?

```
protected void gvEmployeeLeaves_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        btnSearch.Enabled="false";
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem :** `"false"` is not a valid boolean value(it is a string)

so you should change either string `"false"` to `false` or convert string `"false"` to boolean.

You can directly assign the `false`  to the Enabled property without double quotes as below:

```
btnSearch.Enabled = false;
```

**OR**

You can convert the string `false` to boolean value using `Convert.ToBoolean()` method and then assign

Try This:

```
btnSearch.Enabled=Convert.ToBoolean("false");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are providing string instead of boolean value. Just remove the double quotes:

```
btnSearch.Enabled = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void gvEmployeeLeaves_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        btnSearch.Enabled=Convert.ToBoolean("false");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void gvEmployeeLeaves_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        btnSearch.Enabled=false; /*btnSearch.Enabled="false"; is wrong
  }
```